# FOR cycle for attribute in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to do a FOR cycle, which will increase a number in attribute name in brackets "0, 1, etc." *@cpu[0], @cpu[1],...* and then display the value of attribute, but I do not know if it is even possible. The FOR cycle works good, but the xpath does not display anything.

I have this XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <root version="1.2">
    <sample cpu0="20" cpu1="30"></sample>
  </root>
```

And this is my XSL document:

```
<xsl:call-template name="incrementValue">
    <xsl:with-param name="i">0</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>    

<xsl:template name="incrementValue">
  <xsl:param name="i"/>
    <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= 10">
      <xsl:value-of select="/root/*/@cpu[i]" />
      <xsl:call-template name="incrementValue">
        <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I know that I can display the values normally ("value-of select="/root/*/@cpu0", etc.), but when I will have for example 20 cpus I would like to have an automatic process that display all these values.
Do you have some ideas how to do it please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@cpu[0]` would select the attribute named `cpu` for which the positional predicate `[position() = 0]` holds, as position starts with 1 that is never true. And you don't have any attribute named `cpu` anyway. If you want to select the attribute named `cpu0` and you want to construct the name at run-time then you need `@*[local-name() = concat('cpu', $i)]`.

On the other hand I would suggest to simply process `root/*/@*[starts-with(local-name(), 'cpu')]` and sort e.g.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="root/*/@*[starts-with(local-name(), 'cpu')]">
  <xsl:sort select="translate(local-name(), 'cpu', '')" data-type="number"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

I don't see the need to write a named template and some tedious variable increment operation to process some attribute nodes sharing a name prefix.